# How do I use count and group by as a condition for another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

So to preface, I'm a first-year comp sci student and we've only just started on SQL, so forgive me if the solution seems obvious.

We were given a database for Zoo, which has tables for Animals, Keepers, and a link entity (if that's the right word) for care roles, connecting the two.
(Schema below)

```
CREATE TABLE Animal (ID VARCHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(10), Species 
VARCHAR(20),
Age SMALLINT, Sex VARCHAR(1), Weight SMALLINT, F_ID VARCHAR(6), M_ID 
VARCHAR(6));

CREATE TABLE Keeper (Staff_ID VARCHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY, Keeper_Name 
VARCHAR(20), Specialisation VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE Care_Role (ID VARCHAR(6), Staff_ID VARCHAR(6), Role 
VARCHAR(10), PRIMARY KEY (ID, Staff_ID));
```

Now the task we've been given is to work out which Keepers have been caring for more than 10 animals of the same species using the following data:

```
INSERT INTO Animal VALUES 
    ('11', 'Horace', 'Marmoset', 99, 'M', 5, '2','1'),
    ('12', 'sghgdht', 'Marmoset', 42, 'M', 3, '2','1'),
    ('13', 'xgnyn', 'Marmoset', 37, 'F', 3, '1','11'),
    ('14', 'sbfdfbng', 'Marmoset', 12, 'F', 3, '1','11'),
    ('15', 'fdghd', 'Marmoset', 12, 'M', 3, '1','11'),
    ('16', 'Fred', 'Marmoset', 6, 'M', 3, '15','1'),
    ('17', 'Mary', 'Marmoset', 3, 'F', 3, '8','14'),
    ('18', 'Jane', 'Marmoset', 5, 'F', 3, '7','13'),
    ('19', 'dfgjtjt', 'Marmoset', 5, 'M', 3, '16','17'),
    ('20', 'Eric', 'Marmoset', 5, 'M', 3, '12','13'),
    ('21', 'tukyufyu', 'Marmoset', 5, 'M', 3, '12','73'),
    ('31', 'hgndghmd', 'Giraffe', 99, 'M', 5, '201','1'),
    ('32', 'sghgdht', 'Giraffe', 42, 'M', 3, '201','1'),
    ('33', 'xgnyn', 'Giraffe', 37, 'F', 3, '111','1'),
    ('34', 'sbfdfbng', 'Giraffe', 12, 'F', 3, '111','1'),
    ('35', 'fdghd', 'Giraffe', 12, 'M', 3, '111','6'),
    ('36', 'Fred', 'Lion', 6, 'M', 3, '151','111'),
    ('37', 'Mary', 'Lion', 3, 'F', 3, '81','114'),
    ('38', 'Jane', 'Lion', 5, 'F', 3, '71','113'),
    ('39', 'Kingsly', 'Lion', 9, 'M', 3, '161','117'),
    ('40', 'Eric', 'Lion', 11, 'M', 3, '121','113'),
    ('41', 'tukyufyu', 'Lion', 2, 'M', 3, '121','173'),
    ('61', 'hgndghmd', 'Elephant', 6, 'F', 225, '201','111'),
    ('62', 'sghgdht', 'Elephant', 10, 'F', 230, '201','111'),
    ('63', 'xgnyn', 'Elephant', 5, 'F', 300, '111','121'),
    ('64', 'sbfdfbng', 'Elephant', 11, 'F', 173, '111','121'),
    ('65', 'fdghd', 'Elephant', 12, 'F', 231, '111','666'),
    ('66', 'Fred', 'Elephant', 17, 'F', 333, '151','147'),
    ('67', 'Mary', 'Elephant', 3, 'F', 272, '81','148'),
    ('68', 'Jane', 'Elephant', 8, 'F', 47, '71','136'),
    ('69', 'dfgjtjt', 'Elephant', 9, 'F', 131, '161','172'),
    ('70', 'Eric', 'Elephant', 10, 'F', 333, '121','136'),
    ('71', 'tukyufyu', 'Elephant', 7, 'M', 114, '121','731');

INSERT INTO Keeper VALUES 
    ('1', 'Roger', 'tdfhuihiu'),
    ('2', 'Sidra', 'rgegegtnrty'),
    ('3', 'Amit', 'ergetetnt'),
    ('4', 'Lucia', 'dvojivhwivih');

INSERT INTO Care_Role VALUES 
    ('32', '1', 'feeding'),
    ('32', '2', 'washing'),
    ('61', '1', 'feeding'),
    ('62', '1', 'feeding'),
    ('63', '1', 'feeding'),
    ('64', '1', 'feeding'),
    ('65', '1', 'feeding'),
    ('66', '1', 'feeding'),
    ('67', '1', 'feeding'),
    ('68', '1', 'feeding'),
    ('69', '1', 'feeding'),
    ('70', '1', 'feeding'),
    ('71', '1', 'feeding'),
    ('11', '4', 'feeding'),
    ('12', '4', 'feeding'),
    ('13', '4', 'feeding'),
    ('14', '4', 'feeding'),
    ('15', '4', 'feeding'),
    ('16', '4', 'feeding'),
    ('17', '4', 'feeding'),
    ('18', '4', 'feeding'),
    ('19', '4', 'feeding'),
    ('20', '4', 'feeding'),
    ('21', '4', 'feeding');
```

So far what I've managed to come up with is this:

```
SELECT Keeper.Keeper_Name, Animal.Species, COUNT(Animal.Species)
FROM Keeper
    JOIN Care_Role
        ON Keeper.Staff_ID = Care_Role.Staff_ID
    JOIN Animal 
        ON Care_Role.ID = Animal.ID
GROUP BY Animal.Species
```

But this is returning more than just the name (which is what I want), as well as showing all the people who have looked after animals, rather than just those who have looked after 10 or more, I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to help with this? Many thanks!

Comment: Provide sample data is good, could you also provide your expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be returning an error, because `Keeper.Keeper_name` is not in the `GROUP BY`.  You have made a good attempt.  A reasonable way to start the query is:

```
SELECT k.Keeper_Name, a.Species, COUNT(*)
FROM Keeper k JOIN
     Care_Role cr
     ON k.Staff_ID = cr.Staff_ID JOIN
     Animal a
     ON cr.ID = a.ID
GROUP BY k.Keeper_Name, a.Species;
```

This will return the number of animals of a given species that each keeper cares for.

Note the following:

- Table aliases are abbreviations for the table.
- All column names are qualified.
- This uses the shorthand of `COUNT(*)` instead of counting some particular column.

Your question adds an additional condition about 10 animals.  You can fit that in using a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have sorted it, I had been using aliases before, but I'd been having a lot of errors so I had removed them in case that was where the issue was arising.

(edit because I forgot to hold shift and enter):
What exactly do you mean by the column names are qualified? I'm not familiar with the terminology